# Why are my <div>s moving slightly depending on content?

Tags: html, css

So I have two `<div>`s nested inside another .

Something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_sidebar"></div>
    <div class="text_area"></div>
</div>
```

I noticed that when the text_area `<div>` contains enough text, it slightly pushes the left_sidebar  to the left and moves over as well. It doesn't do it when my text posts are short.

This is the CSS I have:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.left_sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 1px solid #777F7F;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.text_area {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 22%;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 45%;
}
```

EDIT: I feel that I should mention that this doesn't happen on my 23inch 1080p monitor, but it does happen on my 11inch 768p monitor.

Comment: what do you means by enough text?

Comment: If I write a long article, it'll happen. I don't think it's because of how much text is in there, I think it has more to do with the width of a line of text reaching a certain point (and it's more likely to reach that point the more lines of text I write). Just my suspicion though.

Comment: Sounds like the right scroll bar is appearing on longer pages, which is a common thing to see. You can force the scroll bar to be there on shorter pages, but it's not really worth it imho. It's just how browsers work.

Comment: this site is not a place for questions like that. we should not debug your code. not mentioning you haven't even bothered to make a jsfiddle/codepen/plunker demonstration of your issue. your codepost here makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @ralph.m, Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks, you just solved my wrinkled forehead, haha.

Comment: @knitevision I'll try to include a demonstration next time, didn't realize how ambiguous my question was. And, uh, I think a significant portion of SO users are using it to debug their code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get rid of `position: absolute;` from `left_sidebar` & `text_area` because I didn't see any clue of this positioning. Instead of `position: absolute;`, using `float:left;` will help you I guess.

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjhmuevL/)**.